# Using node-orangesms to send SMS

Tags: node.js, api, npm, sms

Using NodeJS I wanted to implement the Orange SMS API: http://developer.orange.com/apis/sms-eg/api-reference. I have downloaded the `node-orangesms` npm package for my NodeJS project. However, I am struggling with getting it to work.

I have already obtained a `clientId` and `secret` from developer.orange.com for my project. I have noticed that on the package page on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-orangesms it was not described where the authentication header should be inserted for sendSMS function to work. I am getting this error:

```
{ Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=302
at ClientRequest.onConnect (/home/salma/Desktop/project1/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:165:19)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:551:20) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

and I think this might be the reason why. This is my code so far:

```
var clientId = 'XX';
var secret = 'XX';
var userOptions = {
  proxy: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host    : 'api.orange.com/smsmessaging/v1/outbound/tel%3A%2BXXXXXXXX/requests',
    port    : 8080
  },
  strictSSL: true
}

var OrangeSMS = require('node-orangesms')(clientId, secret, userOptions);

var senderAddress = 'tel:+20XXXXXXXXXX';
var senderName = 'test';

module.exports = {
  sendSMS: function(recipient, content, next) {
    OrangeSMS.sendSMS("tel:+"+recipient, content, senderAddress, senderName);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `https`. It was causing an authentication failure. It worked after changing it to `http`.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of this wrapper is to abstract the authentication process so that you don't have to worry about it.

So technically, you never have to specify the authentication header because the library is doing it for you.

Your issue might be related to a network restriction error maybe?

Comment: Thanks for replying! The problem was the `https`. It was causing an authentication failure. It works now that I changed it to `http`.